# The relation between Vin and Vout (diodes circuit)

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, diodes, homework

Can anyone here tell me if the function I found that relates the Vin to Vout is right?
So I made a mesh analysis to find the current in the first mesh (left to right) and in the second and got that the Vout = (2/11)*Vi +6.328

threshold voltage = 0.7V

[image: diode circuit]

that's how I did it:

[image: my shot]

IS IT RIGHT?

Comment: And your diode model is? 0.7V?

Comment: yes, I forgot it to put it before. Its edited now

Comment: This looks very much like a homework question, so we need you to show us all of your work. Then you can ask a **specific** question about your method rather than "is this right?"

Comment: I put my try in there now

Comment: 0.6 would be a better model for near 1mA but at 1st glance Vo starts at 2.5 +2/3(7.5) -0.7 = 6.8

Comment: I don't think you can bring a single expression for Vo like that because diodes are involved. You will have to solve Vo for different ranges of Vin.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not right. You are trying to use linear circuit analysis techniques on a circuit that has non-linear elements. For example, if you are using an ideal diode model then \$I_2\$ can not be positive...how do your equations account for that?

Comment: then I can say D2 is an open switch and calculate the voltage in there?

Comment: No, you can't say that D2 is open until you show that it is reverse biased. If you assume that it is forward biased and the calculated voltage across the diode is less than its assumed forward voltage, then your assumption is incorrect. You are probably going to need different equations for different ranges of the input voltage.